# Is a "Ranking" query's ORDER BY in FROM subquery is preserved?

Tags: mysql, mariadb

I've read in the following links that the ORDER BY in FROM subquery can be ignored.

Quoted from [MariaDB knowledge base](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/why-is-order-by-in-a-from-subquery-ignored/)

A query such as

```
SELECT field1, field2 FROM 
(SELECT field1, field2 FROM table1 ORDER BY field2 ) alias
```

returns a result set that is not necessarily ordered by field2.

So, given the following query:

```
SELECT CASE 
         WHEN   @prev = x.city_id
            THEN @a
         WHEN @prev := x.city_id
            THEN @a := @a + 1
         END
         `rank`     
FROM 
(SELECT @prev := NULL, @a := 0) y,
(
    SELECT *
    FROM sakila.address a
    ORDER BY a.city_id
) x
```

Will the rows returned from the FROM subquery be in the order specified in the ORDER BY clause?

**Edit:**

How about the query below, will the `x.city_id` be ignored or not?

```
SELECT ....
FROM (
    SELECT CASE 
           WHEN   @prev = x.city_id
              THEN @a
           WHEN @prev := x.city_id
              THEN @a := @a + 1
           END
             `rank`     
    FROM 
        (SELECT @prev := NULL, @a := 0) y,
        sakila.address x

    ORDER BY x.city_id
)
ORDER BY another_order_by_clause
```

---

**How I solved it.**

After looking through the answer and feedbacks from @ypercube and @jkavalik, I decided to explicitly create a temporary table for each inner query that I had.

Reason being as pointed by them, adding LIMIT by a huge number or other hacks might not work in every version of MariaDb or MySQL.

Performance was still good for the query that I did.

e.g:

The second query above is **changed to**

```
   CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE temp1 SELECT CASE 
                   WHEN   @prev = x.city_id
                      THEN @a
                   WHEN @prev := x.city_id
                      THEN @a := @a + 1
                   END
                     `rank`     
            FROM 
                (SELECT @prev := NULL, @a := 0) y,
                sakila.address x                
            ORDER BY x.city_id;

    SELECT ....
    FROM temp1
    ORDER BY another_order_by_clause;
```

Comment: You might probably switch to the old behavior for a while by setting optimizer_switch='derived_merge=off' (or optimizer_switch='derived_merge=off,derived_with_keys=off', depending on the structure of your table)  -- https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/group-by-trick-has-been-optimized-away/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As the article explains: **No, the internal `ORDER BY` will be recognized by MariaDB's optimizer as redundant and will be *"optimized away"*. If you want a result set returned in a specific order, use `ORDER BY` - in the most external level of the query.**

The solution is to use `ORDER BY` in the external query. The `x` subquery (derived table) can be removed and replaced by a simple `sakila.address x` (that's what the optimizer will recognize and do anyway):

```
SELECT CASE 
         WHEN   @prev = x.city_id
            THEN @a
         WHEN @prev := x.city_id
            THEN @a := @a + 1
       END
         `rank`     
FROM 
    (SELECT @prev := NULL, @a := 0) y,
    sakila.address x                    -- remove the derived table

ORDER BY x.city_id ;                    -- add ORDER BY in the external query
```

---

About the second query, yes, I think the `ORDER BY x.city_id` will be ignored, too. The answer in the linked question is 6 years old and is accurate but it's for MySQL (and the versions available then). MariaDB recent improvements on the optimizer make this kind of subqueries with variables, sometimes to fail because the `ORDER BY` is "optimized away".

Comment: What about the query in the edited question of mine? Will the `x.city_id` ignored or not? And so, the answer in this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/532878/how-to-perform-grouped-ranking-in-mysql is not accurate?

Comment: It MAY be - thats the big problem, it sometimes works and sometimes does not because it depends on what path the optimizer choses, the answer is 6 years old and optimizers changed a bit in that time - for instance MariaDB implemented automatic merging of derived tables where possible.

Comment: Edited my answer. Basically what @jkavalik said.

Comment: @jkavalik Then, how do I solve a problem where I need the inner query to be ordered first before executing the outer query. Do I need to create a temp table for each inner query in FROM?

Comment: Yes, creating a temporary table and saving the results of the subquery is probably the best and (if not the only) safe option. You only need to do this when an `ORDER BY` is required in the derived table, not for all subqueries.

Comment: You can make the query "non-mergeable" by using `GROUP BY` or by toggling the proper switch (or probably by adding some big `LIMIT`), but those are only "hacks" to fool the current version into doing something it is not supposed to do. Even automatic indexing of the tmp table might break things.. And half a year later you will have no idea why you did it that way. Be explicit - the sql should be maintainable too, as any other code.

Comment: Hmm, this makes it very hard to complex business queries then because compared to the simplistic example in my answer, I have a long query with multiple inner queries. It works now, but looking at the documentation it is just "MAYBE". So, I need to create a temp table for each inner query. 
Moving away from the question a bit, will creating and destroying multiple temp tables in 1 query execution will cause performance hit? let's say for 1000 rows.

Comment: You'll have to test that (efficiency of using temp tables.) You can also try the trick suggested by jkavalik - add `LIMIT 10000000000` in any such subquery that has `ORDER BY`. I wonder why you need so many subqueries though. What are you calculating? Multiple rankings, based on different orders?

Comment: Hard to explain, but the ordering is done from parts of the columns which need to be processed beforehand in inner queries. It is not only ranking things inside, there are other logics too which need ordering and yes it is based on different orders.
Anyway, I'll accept your answer soon. Just want to see if any other people has different views. Cheers for the help. Much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

MariaDB (in contrary to MySQL) lacks the feature which allows returning ordered results from subqueries. `ORDER BY` is only ordering the results when:

- it is in the outermost (last) query
- if `GROUP BY` is used (in the subquery)
- if a `LIMIT` is given (in the subquery)

The last two options are interesting here, as these are probably never optimized out, because the optimizer may have a hard time to prove that the returned results will be the same.

Therefore, you can force MariaDB to order the results from the subquery, without affecting the query results with a trick:

If you have a primary or unique index available, you could add `GROUP BY` on that column in the subquery, without affecting the returned results, but still have MariaDB order the results. Otherwise you could add `LIMIT 18446744073709551615`.

Comment: I prefer limit/group by over forced temporary table creation, and sometimes you can not move the order by to the outer query.
I'm using MS Access as a frontend for MySQL, wich doesn't allow multiple statements in pass-trough queries. So, for a user in home office, CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE would add another 100 msec UI delay.

Comment: And here is a case, where you can't move the order by to the outer query:
/ renormalization of priority queue, unfinished query /
update rtg_prio inner join
( -- t1 
        SELECT  sorszam, (@sorszam3:=@sorszam3 + 63) as newoffset, (sorszam+prio) as myprio, (cast(`mystart` as signed)  + @sorszam3 - cast(`sorszam` as signed)) as newprio
        FROM rtg_prio cross JOIN (SELECT @sorszam3 := -63) as r cross join (select min(sorszam) mystart from rtg_prio where stat>0) as s
        where stat > 0  order by myprio 
) as t1 on rtg_prio.sorszam = t1.sorszam
SET rtg_prio.PRIO = t1.newprio;